# Ready function of jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, document-ready

I am changing the paragraph text using a very simple jquery , but it isn't working. Please help.

**SORRY FOR NOT LEARING JQUERY FIRST, I JUMPED DIRECTLY TO THE CODE, NOT KNOWING THAT IT NEEDS A SEPARATE jquery file too.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("p").text("The DOM is now loaded and can be manipulated.");


});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I didn't see that you include jQuery script there?

Comment: It's working on my side. Are you sure you have included jquery library?

Comment: in case you added jquery, you should have posted the complete code to get the correct resolution :)

Comment: When writing javascript, you MUST learn how to look at your browser's error console or the debugger console so you can see where your javascript errors are.  Then, errors like this would be much more obvious to you.

Comment: stack overflow is not a substitute for making a REMOTE attempt to read the jquery documentation. If you can't read the first paragraph of the introduction then please do not ask questions http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't [included the jQuery library](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery) in the page, so `$` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Add jquery library

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```